# Prepopulating multiselect picklists in a flow

Tags: picklist, flow

I have a multiselect picklist on a record.
I want to display its current values in a multiselect picklist in a visual flow.
But when I tried setting the value of the picklist to a variable and setting that as the default value in the multiselect picklist, I got "one; two", as opposed to "one" and "two" on separate lines.
Has anyone come up with a way of doing this?

Comment: Best I can come up with is putting the current values above the multiselect picklist field and leaving the default blank.
Then telling the user to only put in new selections if there is a change.
Then only write the picklist if it is not empty.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the documentation, it seems to be normal to get this string containing a series of attributes delimited by semicolons.

> Multi-select picklist fields contain a list of one or more items from
>   which a user can choose multiple items. One of the items can be
>   configured as the default item. Selections are maintained as a string
>   containing a series of attributes delimited by semicolons. For
>   example, a query might return the values of a multivalue picklist as
>   “first value; second value; third value”.

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/field_types.htm#i1435691

Comment: unfortunately when you feed this into a multiselect picklist in a flow, it appears as a string with semicolons, not as separate items on each line.

At the moment, I am trying to figure out if there is a way to pragmatically populate the already selected values, but any HTML code I attempt to put into the picklist is stripped off before the user see it (I tried changing "one; two" to "one<BR>two" and a few other combinations without success.